# ClassCastException одного и того же класса

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, classcastexception

Я пишу плагины для Minectaft и наткнулся на такую ошибку:

```
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'reports' in plugin Report v1
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:648) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1401) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1236) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:46) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:748) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:406) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:679) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:577) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.db.ReportModel cannot be cast to class xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.db.ReportModel (xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.db.ReportModel is in unnamed module of loader org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader @23496b7c; xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.db.ReportModel is in unnamed module of loader org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader @43e215cd)
        at xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.gui.inventory.GUI.modelsToButton(GUI.java:192) ~[?:?]
        at xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.gui.inventory.GUI.createReportsGui(GUI.java:218) ~[?:?]
        at xyz.nifti.makcnm4ik.command.Reports.onCommand(Reports.java:28) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-79a30d7-f4830a1]
        ... 15 more
```

Указывает она на начало цикла. Я прочитал что это связанно с разными загрузчиками классов, но почему это так и как это исправить?

Comment: Этот класс/плагин случаем не загружен два раза? Мб там 2 разных версии грузятся?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim, не понимаю. Можете привести пример? У меня из базы данных запрашиваются объекты, которые преобразуется в их классы-модели, а после в виде массива они используются в GUI. Вот когда я по этому массиву прохожусь вылазит ошибка

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос кодом, чтобы мы могли лучше разобраться в вашей проблеме и найти решение. Решить проблему с разными загрузчиками вряд ли возможно, но вы можете делать сериализацию/десериализацию вашего объекта.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в преобразовании типов ClassCastException.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdF7tfTzqr4&ab_channel=BrandanJones

Comment: Mr. Логика хе-хе